# Using Tiny MCE, but emails are not sending formatted?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, tinymce

I am using tiny mce in a text box and trying to send emails.

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBody" runat="server" Rows="10" class="tinymce"
                                TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
```

but the email which is sent is not formatted..

`<p><span style="background-color: #ff0000;">hello</span></p`>

it shouldnt say all that? just hello with a red background?

```
   Sub SendEmail(ByVal sEmailAddressFrom As String, ByVal sEmailAddressTo As String, ByVal sSubject As String, ByVal sBody As String)
    Dim msg As New MailMessage
    msg.To = sEmailAddressTo
    msg.From = sEmailAddressFrom
    msg.Body = sBody
    msg.Subject = sSubject
    Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "127.0.0.1"
    SmtpMail.Send(msg)
End Sub
```

Comment: What Object are you using to Send the mail - System.Net.Mail ? if so, have you set the IsBodyHtml property on the MailMessage Object to true ?

Comment: Added function i am using to send email

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, as I suspected....

Add the following to your code, and it should work...

```
Sub SendEmail(ByVal sEmailAddressFrom As String, ByVal sEmailAddressTo As String, ByVal sSubject As String, ByVal sBody As String)
    Dim msg As New MailMessage
    msg.To = sEmailAddressTo
    msg.From = sEmailAddressFrom
    msg.Body = sBody
    msg.IsBodyHtml = True 'New Line here
    msg.Subject = sSubject
    Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "127.0.0.1"
    SmtpMail.Send(msg)
End Sub
```